# Как вывести числа с новой строки?

Tags: c#

Нужно вывести числа от A до B включительно, каждое число должно выводиться на новой строке количество раз, равное его значению.

```
int A, B;
Console.WriteLine("Введите первое число: ");
A = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Введите второе число: ");
B = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = A; i <= B; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
                 
    }  
}
```

Например, для A=3, B=5:

```
3 3 3 
4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5
```

Comment: Console.WriteLine("\n");

Comment: Лень не всегда хорошо. Задание картинкой выкладывать нельзя, это неуважение к читателям, ведь текст с картинки нельзя скопировать или найти в поиске. Поэтому «картинку» нужно переосмыслить и сформулировать самому. Еще по-хорошему надо прикладывать свои попытки решения и объяснять что не получилось и почему.

Comment: @EmbraceTradition Что эта строчка должна давать? Используйте `Environment.NewLine`, для кросс-платформености. Да и зачем городить такое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = A; i <= B; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(i + " ");    //числа через пробел
    }
    Console.WriteLine();         //переход на новую строку
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = A; i <= B; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите первое число: ");
            // Не был определен тип, не правильное использование ReadLine
            int A = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Введите второе число: ");
            // Не был определен тип, не правильное использование ReadLine
            int B = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int i = A; i <= B; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }
            }
        }
```